# How to make preventDefault for change on Element UI radio group

Tags: vue.js, element-ui

I'm using Element UI radio button group and I want to use `preventDefault()` when trigering change event:

```html
<el-radio-group @change="changeHandler" v-model="radio1">
   <el-radio-button label="New York"></el-radio-button>
   <el-radio-button label="Washington"></el-radio-button>
   <el-radio-button label="Los Angeles"></el-radio-button>
   <el-radio-button label="Chicago"></el-radio-button>
</el-radio-group>
```

Script:

```js
methods: {
  changeHandler(value, e) { 
    // e is undefined
    // here should be preventDefault
  }
}
```

I tried set second parameter to change function, but it is undefined.

Comment: In your case above , `value` should be the Event Object and `e` should be undefined, just like you have it. Try logging `value` . Please take a look at my answer and accept if it helped.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Element UI works a bit differently. `@change` just returns the value chosen, nothing else. We need to use `native` to access the `Event` object. But `@change.native` won't work, as the change has already happened (if you want to actually prevent the change). As a side note, I would use `disabled` attribute instead (like presented in [documentation](https://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/radio#button-style)). In my opinion for the UX it's weird that a user cannot choose a radio button, but putting that aside.... Use `@click.native` instead if you want to prevent a choice:

```
@click.native="changeHandler"
```

Then you have access to the `Event` object:

```js
changeHandler(e) { 
  console.log(e.target.value)
  if(e.target.value == "Washington") {
    e.preventDefault();
  } 
}
```

**[CODEPEN](https://codepen.io/AJT82/pen/xxbBNBR)**

Comment: good point about the Element UI working differently. Did thought about that too late. only thought about the native behaviour of @change.

Comment: @PascalLamers Yeah, almost missed it myself!

Comment: You are very welcome @a.yushko, glad I could help! :)

Comment: @AJT82 But why first value is undefined?

Comment: what first value?`

Comment: console.log(e.target.value) display two values undefined and "Washington"

Comment: interesting, I didn't even notice that. Put a debugger in the codepen and you will see that the click is triggered for two different elements. So it has to do with how Element UI has been created (css), not with vue itself.

Answer (score 0):

You're having the parameters in the method wrong. The are 2 ways this can go using the @change event handler:

### A

defining a change handler without arguments, like

```
<el-radio-group @change="changeHandler" v-model="radio1" ></el-radio-group>

changeHandler(e) {
   // e will be the Event object
   console.log(e)
}
```

### B

defining a change handler with arguments, put in $event to still include the event object

```
<el-radio-group @change="changeHandler($event, 'string')" v-model="radio1" ></el-radio-group>

changeHandler(e, value) {
   // e will be the Event object
   console.log(e);
   
   // value will be 'string'
   console.log(value);
}
```

Comment: No it dose't help.
Case A and B return value

Comment: What do you mean with "doesnt help"? What error do you have ? What is the desired effect ?

Comment: e returned as value it not a event of change function

Comment: vue does give the event object as first parameter to the event handler. That's a fact. One possibility could be, that this custom component of yours not correctly implement the change event handler. What framework do you use ?